# .NET WebAPI : Custom authorisation header

Tags: .net, authorization, middleware, webapi

I have a .NET 5 Web API project. Most of the API's authenticate using Azure AD so I use the standard Microsoft.Identity.Web library to implement this.

For one particular API which is to be accessed programmatically by 3rd parties, the authorization will be done via a base64 auth header.

I can probably write some middleware to check the header and extract values etc, but as this is only required for one API/controller, is there a better way of implementing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try to  Adding AuthorizeAttribute (eg. APIAuthorizeAttribute) as a new filter to validate Token and check access for all controller in your project.

For more information please check this article :

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1183150/Securing-ASP-NET-Web-API-using-Custom-Token-Based